# Can we take a print from Web View?

Tags: android, printing

My simple question is Can we Print the page from Web View through WIFI printing?
I have made one page and displayed in Web View so, can i print that page?
In emulator it doesn't get any options for that, But in android wifi support phone have the print option.
Please help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try below code

```js
public  void createWebPagePrint(WebView webView) {
  /*if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) 
            return;*/
     PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);
     PrintDocumentAdapter printAdapter = webView.createPrintDocumentAdapter();
     String jobName = getString(R.string.webapp_name) + " Document";
     PrintAttributes.Builder builder = new PrintAttributes.Builder();
     builder.setMediaSize(PrintAttributes.MediaSize.ISO_A5);
     PrintJob printJob = printManager.print(jobName, printAdapter, builder.build());
    
     if(printJob.isCompleted()){
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.print_complete, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
     else if(printJob.isFailed()){
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.print_failed, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
     // Save the job object for later status checking
 }
```

Comment: How to implement it?

Comment: @PraveshAgrawal please explain your requirement I would be able to help you. In my example this method accepts webView on which u have to take a print.

Comment: I want to implement it in such a way so that it can work directly with HTML Print Button and no extra need to press print button to run this function.

Comment: @PraveshAgrawal please check the below answer, if it could help. Post comment if you face any problem or doubt

Answer (score 7):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.print.PrintAttributes;
import android.print.PrintDocumentAdapter;
import android.print.PrintJob;
import android.print.PrintManager;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TempActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView mMainWebview;
    private WebView print_webview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mMainWebview = new WebView(TempActivity.this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_temp);// mention layout of you activity here
        FrameLayout webViewpar = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.webViewParent);
        webViewpar.addView(mMainWebview);
        print_webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.print_view); //view on which you want to take a printout
        mMainWebview.addJavascriptInterface(new TempActivity.WebViewJavaScriptInterface(this), "androidapp"); //
        // "androidapp is used to call methods exposed from javascript interface, in this example case print
        // method can be called by androidapp.print(String)"
        // load your data from the URL in web view
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mMainWebview.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
        } else {
            mMainWebview.loadUrl("your website URL");
        }
    }

    public class WebViewJavaScriptInterface {

        /*
         * Need a reference to the context in order to sent a post message
         */
        public WebViewJavaScriptInterface(Context context) {

        }

        /**
         * method defined by developer, which will be called by web page , from web developer
         * this you can call when want to take a print, either on click of a button or directly
         * Convert HTML data, to be printed,  in form of a string and pass to this method.
         *
         * @param data
         */
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void print(final String data) {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    doWebViewPrint(data);

                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void doWebViewPrint(String ss) {

        print_webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

                createWebPagePrint(view);
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            }
        });
        // Generate an HTML document on the fly:
        print_webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, ss, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
    }

    public void createWebPagePrint(WebView webView) {

        PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);
        PrintDocumentAdapter printAdapter = webView.createPrintDocumentAdapter();
        String jobName = getString(R.string.webapp_name) + " Document";
        PrintAttributes.Builder builder = new PrintAttributes.Builder();
        builder.setMediaSize(PrintAttributes.MediaSize.ISO_A5);
        PrintJob printJob = printManager.print(jobName, printAdapter, builder.build());

        if (printJob.isCompleted()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.print_complete, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (printJob.isFailed()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.print_failed, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It will need to be called like androidapp.print, anyway, answer is pretty good! thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Some android/Ios version will not allow direct printing using window.print(). So the option is putting a floating button to print the page.