# Height issue for converting webview into bitmap

Tags: java, android

I am converting webview as bitmap for printing,my problem is when I click printButton entire webpage not printing, only device height is printed remaining will be white space printed in first attempt,another time click print button entire webpage will be printed.Please tell me to print entire webview in first attempt.I have mentioned below code i used

````
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
 setContentView(R.layout.Main-activity);
bt_print.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
Bitmap bmp = getScreenBitmap();``
}
});
}

public Bitmap getScreenBitmap() {
    final WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
   webView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true); 
   webView.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), 
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
   webView.layout(0, 0, webView.getMeasuredWidth(), webView.getMeasuredHeight()); 

  webView.buildDrawingCache(true);
   Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(webView.getDrawingCache());
  webView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false); // clear drawing cache
   return b;
}```
Below code is Main-activity.xml 
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    style="@style/AppTheme"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.fusion.print" >

      <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

      <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_print"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#1C5C1C"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/btn_button"
        android:text="@string/btn_button"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

</RelativeLayout>
````

Comment: With anything that scrolls, you have two sets of 'frames'.  One set is the visible viewport, usually constrained by the size of the screen of the device.  The other is the content view, which contains all of the data, some of which is visible on screen, and some off screen in the scrollable area.  You need to try to print the content view, not the viewport view.

Comment: Thank you for your reply,i have set content view,but printer will  print device height only,remaining will be white space.Next time click printer will print.I have attached my xml file

Comment: You are capturing your webView content into a bitmap, then looking to print that bitmap.  Have you considered other alternatives?  Here is one example using printer related methods of the webView:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11537726/can-we-take-a-print-from-web-view